# Replace class name on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my ***Markup***. I want to update/replace class name `col-sm-3`
 to `col-md-6` on widow resize *(ex: width < 800)*

```
<div class="llotherlogos-userthumb">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="logo-thumb">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/logos/logo-seven.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo-caption">
                        <div class="ll-category">Business</div>
                        <div class="ll-price"><span>1000BDT</span>5000 BDT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="logo-thumb">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/logos/logo-eight.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo-caption">
                        <div class="ll-category">Business</div>
                        <div class="ll-price"><span>1000BDT</span>5000 BDT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="logo-thumb">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/logos/logo-nine.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo-caption">
                        <div class="ll-category">Business</div>
                        <div class="ll-price"><span>1000BDT</span>5000 BDT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="logo-thumb">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/logos/logo-ten.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo-caption">
                        <div class="ll-category">Business</div>
                        <div class="ll-price"><span>1000BDT</span>5000 BDT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
var otherlogos = function(){

    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

  var myLogos = document.querySelectorAll(".llotherlogos-userthumb  .col-sm-3");
   if(ww < 800){
    myLogos.className.replace(col-sm-3, col-md-6);

  }
}

window.onresize = otherLogos;
```

Comment: Besides the fact that there are a number of problems with this JavaScript (which I can get into if you want me to), why not use `col-sm-3` and `col-md-6` together, instead of replacing one with the other? That's the way the Bootstrap CSS is supposed to work, so that adjustment is automatic with CSS alone.

Comment: **" "** (*double quotes*) around col-sm-3 and col-md-6 could help.

Comment: Okay fine, I want to change any class name on resize, how?

Comment: Since you are using `querySelectorAll()`, you need to use a for loop

Comment: Please give me a example based on my code

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
myLogos.className.replace(col-sm-3, col-md-6);
```

To be:

```
myLogos[0].classList.replace('col-sm-3', 'col-md-6');
```

(`querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements, even if only one element matches, hence the need for `myLogos[0]`.)

To do this for multiple elements, you'd need something like this (explicit `for` loop, because I think `foreach` doesn't work here):

```
for (let i = 0; i < myLogos.length; ++i)
  myLogos[i].classList.replace('col-sm-3', 'col-md-6');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just require to use `toggle` for achieving the goal. The example is given below:

```
myLogos.classList.toggle('col-sm-3');
myLogos.classList.toggle('col-md-6');
```

or

```
var myLogos = document.querySelectorAll(".llotherlogos-userthumb  .col-sm-3");
var classes = myLogos.classList;

var result = classes.replace("col-sm-3", "col-md-6");
console.log(result);
```

For more info on above access this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace)

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you could do something like this

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if($(window).width()<800){
            $('.llotherlogos-userthumb').children().removeClass('col-sm-3').addClass('col-md-6');
        }else{
            $('.llotherlogos-userthumb').children().removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-sm-3');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but only vanilla Javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code:

```
  enter$( window ).resize(function() {
  var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

  <==========now select id or element==============>


  $("#a1").addClass( "my-hidden").removeClass("my-disply");
    // code here
   });
```